# Odd response from accessing JSON variable

Tags: php, file-get-contents, json

I have this code:

```
<?php
$jsonurl = "http://api.wipmania.com/json";
$jsonfgc = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
$json = json_decode($jsonfgc, true);

foreach ( $json["address"] as $address => $country_code )
    {   
      echo $address["country_code"];
    }
?>
```

However, when I print this out, I only get "cccccr". I try just `echo`ing `$country_code` but I get "North AmericaNA-United StatesUS-". Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're actually trying to grab the country code, do the following:

```
echo $json['address']['country_code'];
```

A loop is not required there.

---

> I try just echoing $country_code but I get "North AmericaNA-United StatesUS-". Any help?

For an explanation as to why this is happening:

You probably didn't add any linebreaks in your code. So it appears as if it's a single string. It's actually not.

Try:

```
foreach ( $json["address"] as $address => $country_code )
{   
    echo $country_code."<br/>\n";
}
```

The output should be:

```
North America
NA
-
United States
US
-
```

[**See the difference!**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AFKpDI)

Comment: Thanks! Why is the loop happening, though? I get "USUSUSUSUSUS" when I try your second code.

Comment: @DayloStar: As I've mentioned in my answer, you **don't** need a loop if you just want the country code **only**. Just echo it outside the loop and it'll print `US` once.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using `$address` as array it is just an index.

If you want only country code

Use:

```
//foreach ( $json["address"] as $address => $country_code )
//{   
  echo $json["address"]["country_code"];
//}
```

Comment: I used `json_decode($jsonfgc, true);` which decodes the json as an array.

Comment: it is must an array but $address["country_code"]; is not posible because in foreach il $address is just a variable

Answer (score 0):

Try printing it out first, it will make it much easier to figure it out. (for debuggin ofcourse)

```
var_dump($json); // or print_r( $json ); if you want
```

To print keys and values you can use this:

```
foreach( $json['address'] AS $index => $value ) {
  echo "$index - $value<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$jsonurl = "http://api.wipmania.com/json";
$jsonfgc = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
$json = json_decode($jsonfgc, true);

echo $json["address"]["country_code"]; //if json return single value
//if return multiple then execute it
foreach ( $json as $key => $val )
    {   
      if($key=="address"){
      echo $json[$key]['country_code'];
      };

    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I would've upvoted your answer but I don't have enough rep.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `foreach` here. Just use:

```
echo $json["address"]["country_code"];
```

Note that in PHP 5.4 and later, your code would actually generate warnings: "Warning: Illegal string offset 'country_code'". In your `foreach` loop (which enumerates all properties in the object), `$address` is a string (the property name), not an array.